# Setting Navigation View MenuItem style programmatically

Tags: android, navigationview

Is it possible to set the style of a MenuItem in the new navigation view programmatically? I am building the menu dynamically and cannot use a static XML file. I've been unable to find any information on this.

UPDATE: I am familiar with setting title and icon, but not how I can e.g. set the alpha of the text.

UPDATE 2: In the class NavigationView there is `setItemTextColor(ColorStateList)`. As far as I can tell it is not possible to set individual item colors?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to set menu icon:

First set `navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null)`,

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_nav_view);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

and get the menuitem, set icon for it.

```
MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);
menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.nav_new_drawable);
```

And also can set text color, like this:

```
navigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList textColor);
```

And set item background, like this:

```
navigationView.setItemBackgroundResource(int resId)
```

---Edit---

Since you already know the above, you can try below code.

```
<color name="test_alpha_color">#40999999</color>

MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.test_alpha_color)), 0, s.length(), 0);
menuItem.setTitle(s);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I am familiar with setting icons. What I meant by styling is changing text color (alpha) etc.

Comment: Can my revised answer help you?

Comment: That worked like a charm! I did not know that the menu items could receive a SpannableString..!

Comment: `setItemBackgroundResource(int resId)` will change all menu items, however I am interested in changing the background for specific menu items. How can I achieve this?

Comment: setItemTextColor has some problems in 25.0.0 support library version. I couldn't set selected state color. The states are here `
            int [][] states = new int [][]{
                    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled, -android.R.attr.state_pressed, -android.R.attr.state_selected}, 
                    new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, 
                    new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_selected},
                    new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_pressed}  
            };`