# Changing alpha on icon using navigation view

Tags: android, navigationview

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913972/setting-navigation-view-menuitem-style-programmatically) I learned that it's possible to use a SpannableString in order to change text color on the title of a menu item (using the "new" navigation view).

Previously, when I was using a view, I could change the icon alpha by doing iconView.setAlpha(0.5);

Is it possible to do this using navigation view without creating a new drawable with the desired alpha?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't see it:

```
menuItem.getIcon().setAlpha(128);
```